# Having trouble understanding how to call values in a JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, momentjs

I'm using knockout.js and moment.js to compute some values about a given month. The following code works as intended:

```
var calendarViewModel = {
    selectedMonth: ko.observable(moment().format("M")),
    daysInMonth: ko.observable(moment().month(3).daysInMonth())
};

ko.applyBindings(calendarViewModel);
```

The returned values are "4" for selectedMonth and "30" for daysInMonth.

But what I *want* to do is compute the value of daysInMonth based on the current value of selectedMonth (which will change). The best code I could come up with was this:

```
var calendarViewModel = {
    selectedMonth: ko.observable(moment().format("M")),
    daysInMonth: ko.observable(moment().month(calendarViewModel.selectedMonth() - 1).daysInMonth())
};

ko.applyBindings(calendarViewModel);
```

I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'selectedMonth' of undefined` in the console.
The thing I'm having trouble understanding is how to reference selectedMonth properly in this context. If I create selectedMonth in some other generic variable outside of my viewModel everything I'm doing works fine.

I'm quite certain that this has to do with my (poor) understanding of JavaScript objects and nothing to do with the libraries themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a [computed](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html) for that:

```
var calendarViewModel = function(){
    var self = this;
    self.selectedMonth = ko.observable(moment().format("M"));
    self.daysInMonth = ko.computed(function(){
        var selectedMonth = self.selectedMonths();
        return moment().month(selectedMonth - 1).daysInMonth();
    });
};

ko.applyBindings(new calendarViewModel());
```

As to the difference... here we are creating an actual instance of a `calendarViewModel` which will set up the `this` context the way you expect.

It also uses a closure to ensure you can access your own members correctly inside the `computed`.

Comment: This works exactly as intended, thanks! If you have a second for a quick follow up, I'm now confused about how to write a new value to selectedMonth (b/c of self), though I probably just need to go read up on some of this. Thanks again!

Comment: @binaryorganic - Normally you would let this be handled via data bindings, but if you wanted to directly write a new value, you could just write it directly doing `self.selectedMonth(4)` or something like that. You could create a method that you can call, or save an instance of your view model off to a local variable for later use. As for JavaScript, I would highly recommend reading Douglas Crockford's **JavaScript: The Good Parts**